# Laravel query for a range of time

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I am looking for a way to make a query which compares time, morning - 6 to 9, day - 9 to 12 , evening 12 - 5

Right now, I am using an `select` option in html

```
<select name="time" id="time">
          <option disabled value="">Choose A Time</option>
          <option value="06:00 - 09:00">Morning - 06:00 - 09:00 </option>
          <option value="10:00 - 13:00">Day - 10:00 - 13:00 </option>
          <option value="14:00 - 18:00">Evening - 14:00 - 18:00</option>
        </select>
```

And I am trying to query it like this, `datetime` I get it from the database and it's like `2017-12-13 06:15:00`

```
    $query->whereTime('datetime', '>=', $request->get('time').':00')                    
    });
```

I have no idea how I can compare a range of time, like compare `06:00-09:00` with `06:15`

Comment: What is the data type of the `datetime` column?

Comment: It's `datetime` datatype

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can make use of the same query as above to find the table rows between two times.

```
$query->whereTime('timestamp', '>=', \Carbon\Carbon::parse('06:00'))
     ->whereTime('timestamp', '<=', \Carbon\Carbon::parse('06:30'))
```

Dont concatenate date string like this,

```
$request->get('time').':00')
```

This is not quite appropriate, and you might fail with this approach.

Comment: Okay, but I have like `06:00-09:00` how can I use carbon parse on  this, one for `06:00` and one for `09:00`

Comment: $morning_time_array = explode('-','06:00-09:00'); $morning_time_array[0] will be '06:00' also you should use whereBetween like: ->whereBetween('time', ['06:00', '09:00'])->get();